# Autofill remaining height with padding

Tags: html, css

I want my nav anchors' padding to be what's remaining in the nav. I've set it to have a `max-height: 90px;`. What I don't want to do is apply a fixed padding onto them like `padding: 36px 0;`. How can I possibly achieve that without adjusting it myself?

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 90px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

nav a {
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: why padding exactly? you can simply have the element to be full height, no?

Comment: Just need to be able to click on it while hovering over the remaining padding. Elements inside are of different font-size meaning I would have to apply separate padding styles to each element that has a different font-size.

Comment: so as I said, you don't really need padding but you simply need full height links

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the `<nav>` an `align-items` value of `stretch`, and make the `<a>` tags flex boxes as well, with `align-items: center`:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 90px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

nav a {
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think what he want is to make the remain nav's content height and width become padding

Comment: @EthanVu You can't do that without fixed widths and heights. With the example I provided, it achieves the same effect (the entirety of the orange areas are clickable)